# PHP curl error with RapidSSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have bought an RapidSSL cert with my cPanel shared hosting, and now when I am trying to open connection with curl to google.com, just for example, I got following error:

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I am testing with following code:

```
<?php
$conn = curl_init();

$settings = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com',
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS => 2000,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => 2000,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => '/home/username/ssl/certs/cacert.pem'
);

curl_setopt_array($conn, $settings);

if ($rawResponse = curl_exec($conn)) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($conn);
    var_dump($info);
} else {
    echo curl_error($conn);
}
?>
```

I have tried with adding SSL .crt files, but I am still facing same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Contact your hosting? They'll ivah fix the issue or tell you the problem - it may be you have to wait X days for the service to start if the issuer is not returning the SSL cert

Comment: The certificate you bought for your server is unrelated to what you need to use as CA when contacting another server (i.e. you are the client). In fact you don't even need to have your own server certificate to contact other servers using https. You probably have the wrong CA certificates in CURLOPT_CAINFO or the file is not readable by the web server executing your PHP code.

Comment: There is also a certificate issued on servers hostname itself. I am not sure where to start to solve issue.